# Position afollestad MaterialDialog below a button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, popupwindow

Is there an option to  position https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs below a button as like the mock up I have attached .

Or is there any other library to fulfill my requirement.

[image]

Comment: Due you want to open dialog below the filter icon when user click on the filter icon right

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the location of the clicked UI that is your **Filter icon** `ImageView`. You have to use the

> ```
> getLocationOnScreen() API and PopUpWindow component.
> ```

This is the sample code for inflating the FilterUI

```
    text_click=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_click);

          text_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  int[] locationOfView = new int[2];
                  text_click.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfView);
                  final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map_view, null, false);
                  final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(mView, 500, 500, false);
                  popUp.setTouchable(true);
                  popUp.setFocusable(true);
                  popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.transparent)));
                  popUp.showAtLocation(mView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, locationOfView[0], (locationOfView[1]+ text_click.getHeight()));
              }
          });
```

Comment: No I am  still not getting the exact position .